# Haxe and jQuery Extern Library each function

Tags: javascript, jquery, haxe

I decided to learn haxe to compile JavaScript, the problem I face is that there is little info and example on how to use this language to achieve functionality of plain JavaScript. Maybe someone can help me to understand how can I utilize jQuery each function as it does not seem to work. It gives me an error when compiling "js.html.Node has no field width"

Here is the code.

```
import js.Lib;
import js.Browser;
import jQuery.*;

class Main {

    static private var _jqSlider:JQuery;

    static public function main():Void {

        new JQuery(function():Void { //when document is ready
            myFunc();
        });

    }

    static private function myFunc() {
        _jqSlider = new JQuery("aSlider");

        _jqSlider.children().each(function(i,ele) {
            trace(ele.width());
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks.
I am using these jQuery lib http://lib.haxe.org/p/jQueryExtern,  I tried trace( JQuery.cur.width() );  gives me the folowing Class has no field cur,

```
static private function myFunc() {
        _jqSlider = new JQuery("aSlider");

        trace( "hello" ); // works fine as  console.log("hello")

        _jqSlider.children().each(function(i,ele) {
            var ele = new JQuery(ele);
            trace( "hello" ); // Action Ignored
            trace(ele.width()); // Action Ignored
        });
    }'
```

This is the code it outputs to javascript

```
(function (console) { "use strict";
    var Main = function() { };
    Main.main = function() {
        $(function() {
            Main.myFunc();
        });
    };
    Main.myFunc = function() {
        Main._jqSlider = $("aSlider");
        console.log("hello");
        Main._jqSlider.children().each(function(i,ele) {
            var ele1 = $(ele);
            console.log("hello");
            console.log(ele1.width());
        });
    };
    Main.main();
    })(typeof console != "undefined" ? console : {log:function(){}});
```

Comment: What module loader are you using? How are you modifying jQuery to be compliant with ES6 modules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is rather a JQuery issue.

According to the [jquery docs](https://api.jquery.com/each/), `ele` is indeed a plain Element, not a JQuery object, and thus has no `width()` method.

You can either create a new JQuery object like this:

```
var $ele = new JQuery( ele );
trace( $ele.width() ); // should work
```

or use `JQuery.cur`, which will translate to `$( this )` in JS.

```
trace( JQuery.cur.width() );
```

See http://api.haxe.org/js/JQuery.html

AFAIK, both solutions are equivalent, the latter being more concise and probably more "jquery-like".

You seem to be using a different jQuery extern than the [official one](http://api.haxe.org/js/JQuery.html), though, since you import `jQuery.*` instead of `js.JQuery`.

If so, please provide more info as to which lib you use.

Comment: I added info into the question sorry I still don't find it counter intuitive to add code into comment space.

Comment: You should really use the official JQuery extern from the standard lib.
I believe `jQueryExtern` is deprecated, now that Andy maintains the std's